# How to change baseline patient in Predict function in rms package in R?

Tags: r, cox-model, rms

I am doing a time dependent Cox model using cph function in rms package. I use Predict and plot.Predict to plot the hazard ratio on y axis and a continuous covariate (e.g. LDL cholesterol) on X axis for 3 levels of a treatment. I get 3 curves for 3 treatment across the range of my continous covariate LDL. I use the R code below:

```
dd<- with (mydata, datadist( age, sex, LDL, Treatment))
options(datadist='dd')
S<-Surv(mydata$tstart, mydata$tstop, mydata$followUpTime)
fit <- cph( S ~ rcs(age,3) + sex + rcs(LDL,4) + Treatment, x=T, y=T, data=mydata)
plot(Predict(fit, LDL, Treatment, fun='exp'))
```

The hazard ratio I get on Y axis comes from applying "exp" on "log relative hazard" or Xbeta produced by Predict function. This hazard ratio is the hazard relative to the "baseline" patient - a theoretical patient with all covariates set to 0. 
My problem is that I want to make a plot where I compare hazard to a pre-defined patient (e.g. 50 year-old, Male, LDL=80) and not the baseline. I mean I simply want to replace the theoretical baseline patient (all covariates=0) with a patient I define.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `?contrast.rms` and see the examples that involve plotting.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. In truth, it is more of a comment at present. Can you expand on this a little?

Comment: It is a complete answer.  I don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Dr. Harrell! I am wondering if the following code would be the answer to my question above? I would appreciate a confirmation from you or other experts:

```
library(rms)
dd <- datadist(mydata)
options(datadist='dd')
S <- with(mydata, Surv(start, tstop, followUpTime))
fit <- cph( S ~ rcs(age,3) + sex + rcs(LDL,4) + Treatment, x=T, y=T, data=mydata)

# A sequence of LDLs across LDL range in data by 5 units 
LDLs <- seq(10, 300, by=5) 
#Reference is a patient with Treatment=1 and LDL=80, and the rest of covariates at  
# their medians or default references for categorical variables as performed in cph fit 
# (e.g. age= median of age [50 years], sex= default ref. [Male]).
w1 <- contrast( fit, list(Treatment=1, LDL=LDLs), list(Treatment=1, LDL=80) )
w2 <- contrast( fit, list(Treatment=2, LDL=LDLs), list(Treatment=1, LDL=80))
w3 <- contrast( fit, list(Treatment=3, LDL=LDLs), list(Treatment=1, LDL=80))

#Plot separately for each treatment. (used exp() to get HR=Hazard Ratio) :
xYplot(Cbind(exp(Contrast), exp(Lower), exp(Upper)) ~ LDLs, data=w1, ylab='HR, Treatment1 – Reference Patient')
xYplot(Cbind(exp(Contrast), exp(Lower), exp(Upper)) ~ LDLs, data=w2, ylab='HR, Treatment2 – Reference Patient')
xYplot(Cbind(exp(Contrast), exp(Lower), exp(Upper)) ~ LDLs, data=w3, ylab='HR, Treatment3 – Reference Patient')

#To make a plot with all 3 treatment curves, I made a data-frame by extracting
# Contrast, Upper and Lower using w1$Contrast, w2$Contrast etc. and using rbind. 
# Then I could use ggplot or matplot to get a plot all in one. Not shown here.

#--------------A second shorter solution? ----------------
w.all <- contrast( fit, list(Treatment=c(1,2,3), LDL=LDLs), list(Treatment=1, LDL=80), conf.type='simultaneous' )
xYplot(Cbind(exp(Contrast), exp(Lower), exp(Upper)) ~ LDLs, data=w.all, ylab='HR, Treatment – Reference Patient')
#This one gave a very similar plot as above but one needs to find a way to label and color by Treatment….
```

Comment: Since you are not allowing treatment to interact with LDL, and you probably did not mean to vary treatment and LDL simultaneously, you should be able to do this with one call to `contrast`.  I'm going to edit your code to tidy up a few things.

Comment: Thank you! 
It would also be nice to know which code solution would be OK if I had and LDL-Treatment interaction?

Comment: For that, your approach of requesting separate LDL contrasts for each level of treatment would be good (or convert to separate treatment contrasts for each LDL level).  You can also create two larger data frames to compare that generate all the contrasts with one call to `contrast`.